# How to initialize backend instance hours instead of frontend instance hours in google app engine python?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, backend

i have made backends.yaml file it is consuming my frontend instance hours instead i wants it to consume my backend instance hours. My backends.yaml file is

```
application: ias-game-serv


version: 1

module: gprofile

runtime: python27

api_version: 1

threadsafe: yes

handlers:

   - url: /push/.*
     script: push.app

- url: /admin/.*
  script: admin.app
  login: admin

libraries:
- name: webapp2
  version: "2.5.2"
- name: ssl
  version: latest
- name: jinja2
  version: latest

manual_scaling:
  instances: 10
  idle_timeout: 15m
```

or i m using another one

backends:

- name: crawler
  instances: 10
  start: push.app
  idle_timeout: 10m
- name: crawler1
  instances: 10
  start: admin.app
  idle_timeout: 15m